# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expect

Tags: php-5.2.x.x

I get error

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ‘)’ in site.com/app/code/community/EbayEnterprise/Affiliate/Helper/Data.php on line 41
```

from Data.php

```
37 public function getAllProgramIds() 
 38 { 
 39 $config = Mage::helper(’eems_affiliate/config’); 
40 return array_unique(array_filter(array_map( 
 41 function ($website) use ($config) { 
 42 return $config->getProgramId($website->getDefaultStore()); 
 43 }, 
 44 Mage::app()->getWebsites() 
 45 ))); 
 46 }
```

this code for php 5.3 - but I use only php 5.2.17, and can not apdate - please help change this line 41 - that can be work on php 5.2.17

Answer (score 4):

First: **you don't want to do this.** You want to upgrade your PHP. 5.2 is so extremely outdated at this point you're a sitting duck for every script kid out there. The reason this code doesn't work is because PHP 5.2 doesn't support closures.

```
public function getAllProgramIds() 
{ 
    $config = Mage::helper(’eems_affiliate/config’); 

    $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

    $ids = array();
    foreach($websites as $website) {
        $ids[] = $config->getProgramId($website->getDefaultStore());
    }

    return array_unique($ids);
}
```

I think that does what you want.

*Upgrade your PHP!*